# How to add static text to input value

Tags: javascript, php

I have an input element and what I want to do is when user types this static text will always appear after the user input.

```
h "staticTextHere"
hello "staticTextHere"
hello world "staticTextHere"
```

I tried some techniques but there are so much problem here. Is there any idea how to achieve this?

Here is my codes;

```
<input type="text" id="staticTextId" name="staticTextName" ..... />
```

And js;

```
.on('keydown', function (event) {
         var textLength = document.getElementById($id).value.length;
         document.getElementById($id).value = document.getElementById($id).value.substr(0,textLength - staticText.length) + staticText;
 });
```

Comment: should the "staticTextHere" be within the input or "just as it is" text anywhere on the page?

Comment: You can do it, but don't. What if user `CTRL + SHIFT + END + DEL`, or just `DEL`, or move cursor to end and `Backspace`, etc... So hard to handle all cases.

Comment: @UnskilledFreak "staticTextHere" must be within the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain JS version: [Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/h677zt4f/4/)

jQuery : [Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/h677zt4f/3/)

```
document.getElementById("staticTextId").addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var str = this.value;
    var suffix = " static text";

    if(str.search(suffix) === -1){
        str += suffix;
    }

    var actualLength = str.length - suffix.length;

    // set the value
    this.value = str.substr(0,actualLength) + suffix;

    // set cursor position
    this.setSelectionRange(actualLength,actualLength);    
});
```

Comment: your code working perfectly but only problem is with "del" key. Can you handle "del" key?

Comment: add event to the func arglist and katch the keycode of "del"

Comment: @UnskilledFreak I already did but dont know what to do to handle del

Comment: @hellzone didn't know exactly, but try by `console.log(event);` and you'll find some infos about the pressed key and its number, gues it was called keycode

Answer (score 1):

Misunderstood the question, now I get ya - This works but agree with @lolka_bolka - there's lots that can go wrong

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/b13zh0yh/4/)

```
<input type="text" id="staticTextId" name="staticTextName" onkeyup="appendInput();" />

function appendInput(){
    var el = document.getElementById('staticTextId');
    var pos = doGetCaretPosition (el)
    if(el.value){
      var yourText = ' your text'
      if(el.value.indexOf(yourText)<1){
        el.value = el.value + yourText;
      }
      setCaretPosition(el, pos)
    }
}

function doGetCaretPosition (ctrl) {
    var CaretPos = 0;   // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
    ctrl.focus ();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange ();
        Sel.moveStart ('character', -ctrl.value.length);
        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
    return (CaretPos);
}

function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos){
    if(ctrl.setSelectionRange)
    {
        ctrl.focus();
        ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
    }
    else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
        var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: only problem is "del" key. can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

i've tried it with your text and it will only be added if the text is not in there and the user left the element (blur) and got this:

script js:

```
function makeStatic(elem) {
    var staticText = "staticTextHere"
    if(elem.value.indexOf(staticText)==-1) {
        elem.value = elem.value + " " + staticText;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="staticTextId" name="staticTextName" value="" onblur="makeStatic(this);">
```

hope this is what ur looking for